# Showing equal lengths of sides of triangles with a ditto-like symbol in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

How may I show the equality of the two sides `AC` and `A'C'` by drawing two red-coloured line segments perpendicular to `AC` and `A'C'`?

[image]

```
     \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
     \usepackage{blindtext}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
     \usetkzobj{all}
      \usepackage{color}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDefPoint(3,6){C}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,0.5){M}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-0.5){L}
\tkzDrawSegment[red](M,L)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!40](B,A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A^{'}}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){B^{'}}
\tkzDrawSegment(A^{'},B^{'})
\tkzDefPoint(3,6){C^{'}}
\tkzDrawSegment(A^{'},C^{'})
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A^{'})
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B^{'})
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C^{'})
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,0.5){M}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-0.5){L}
\tkzDrawSegment[red](M,L)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!40](B,A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\tkzMarkSegment[color=green,pos=0.5,mark=|||](B,C)
```

Code:

```
     \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
     \usepackage{blindtext}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
     \usetkzobj{all}
      \usepackage{color}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](A,B)
\tkzDefPoint(3,6){C}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=blue,pos=0.5,mark=||](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=green,pos=0.5,mark=|||](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
%\tkzDefPoint(2.5,0.5){M}
%\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-0.5){L}
%\tkzDrawSegment[red](M,L)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!40](B,A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A'}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){B'}
\tkzDrawSegment(A',B')
\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](A',B')
\tkzDefPoint(3,6){C'}
\tkzDrawSegment(A',C')
\tkzMarkSegment[color=blue,pos=0.5,mark=||](A',C')
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=green,pos=0.5,mark=|||](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A')
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B')
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C')
%\tkzDefPoint(2.5,0.5){M}
%\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-0.5){L}
%\tkzDrawSegment[red](M,L)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1 cm, draw=blue, fill=blue!40](B,A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is PERFECT!